# Name of an English-dubbed Japanese show about a man who became a giant robot

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember back in the late 70's or early 80's a show about a man who became a giant, possibly a robot, and fought monsters. I am fairly sure it is not Ultraman. I remember his giant form was a brownish colour. it aired on WTBS and was live action. One episode that stands out has him blinded in his giant form and when he returns to human size his eyes look as if they were burned shut and scabbed over. I also remember vaguely there was a young boy who always seemed to be around whenever he fought the monsters, for some reason or another.

Edit #1
After checking on the suggestions I can say it isn't Johnny Sokko or Ambassador Magma

I have also ruled out Ryūsei Ningen Zone(Zone Fighter)

Edit #2

still looking for the show's name and after a bit more research , checking pictures online, the robot form of the hero looked a lot like Spectreman (already ruled out) except for the point on his head. I know this is of little help, but I thought it worth mentioning

Comment: I think I remember this show. I was thinking about it myself just today and decided to search for it. I seem to remember the guy that turned into a robot would come back at the end of the episode wounded, bandaged up or whatever. Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: You may be conflating Ultraman with _[Johnny Sokko and his Flying Robot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_Robo_(TV_series))_?

Comment: This post feels like a setup to show just how many shows involve giant fighty robots.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like [*Johnny Sokko and His Flying Robot*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_Robo_%28tokusatsu%29):

- Not [*Ultraman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraman)!
- Robot has [brownish bits](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2057717/) (and blueish bits).
- [Young boy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0170962/) is always around.
- BONUS: Also not [Spectreman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectreman)!

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like [*Ambassador Magma*/*The Space Giants*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambassador_Magma):

- Not [*Ultraman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraman)!
- The biggest robot, "Goldar," is brownish [(really goldish)](https://www.google.com/search?q=the+space+giants&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X).
- [Young boy](http://motionempire.org/Browse_TV-Shows__The_Space_Giants__15209.html) is always around.

Comment: Man, I used to love Space Giants. Though I'd forgotten (or didn't know) the name.

Answer (score 3):

Ultraseven is "not Ultraman", and ran on WTBS

[image]

He had a human form, and children were often seen in the episodes.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Spectreman? This is a gold superhero that as far as I know did air on WTBS back in the early 80's.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest Kamen Rider but he wasn't brown and I don't think he turn giant sized. Kamen did have a show during the early 70's though. The pic below is from a show called Dinosaur corps Koseiden. He's kinda brown but from what I learned I don't think he becomes giant. I also added a picture of johnny sokko's robot, a different picture of Kamen Rider, and ambassador magma as comparisons. I suck at editing so they are in no particular order.[image]. [image][image]

[image]